# Ruby on Rails: Getting Form Input to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, wunderground

I'm still learning more about Rails and I'm starting to play around with APIs, but I can't seem to figure out how to get an input from a form to the Model.

I want to take the User input (in the form of a zip code) and have it spit out the weather info at that user location.

Form on `home.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag(root_path) do %>
  <%= label_tag :zip, "ENTER YOUR ZIPCODE TO FIND YOUR WEATHER"  %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag :zip,'', placeholder: "e.g. 91765 " %>
  <%= submit_tag "show me the weather!" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller `pages_controller.rb`

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @weather_lookup = WeatherLookup.new(params[:zip])
  end
end
```

Model `weather_lookup.rb`

```
class WeatherLookup
  attr_accessor :temperature, :weather_condition, :city, :state, :zip

  def initialize(zip)
    self.zip = zip
    zip = 91765 if zip.blank?
    weather_hash = fetch_weather(zip)
    weather_values(weather_hash)
  end

  def fetch_weather(zip)
    p zip
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/API-KEY-HERE/geolookup/conditions/q/#{zip}.json")
  end

  def weather_values(weather_hash)
    self.temperature = weather_hash.parsed_response['current_observation']['temp_f']
    self.weather_condition = weather_hash.parsed_response['current_observation']['weather']
    self.city = weather_hash.parsed_response['location']['city']
    self.state = weather_hash.parsed_response['location']['state']
  end
end
```

I'm not exactly sure how to get the input from the form to the model. This is literally just to show the weather. I'm not trying to save anything in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form helper defaults to "POST" if you don't provide a method. From the looks of your controller, "GET" is what you want. [Here's some documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) to provide additional context. The updated form:

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag :zip, "ENTER YOUR ZIPCODE TO FIND YOUR WEATHER"  %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :zip,'', placeholder: "e.g. 91765 " %>
    <%= submit_tag "show me the weather!" %>
<% end %>
```

Next, if you try to instantiate your `@weather_lookup` variable without `params[:zip]`, Rails will throw an error. Adding a conditional to your controller will solve this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if params[:zip]
      @weather_lookup = WeatherLookup.new(params[:zip])
    end
  end

end
```

Be sure your routes are set up. Something defining `root` should exist in `routes.rb`. For example:

```
  root "pages#home"
```

I believe you also have to parse the JSON into a hash inside your model. Adding that to the `weather_values` method:

```
  def weather_values(weather_json)
    weather_hash = JSON.parse weather_json
    self.temperature = weather_hash.parsed_response['current_observation']['temp_f']
    self.weather_condition = weather_hash.parsed_response['current_observation']['weather']
    self.city = weather_hash.parsed_response['location']['city']
    self.state = weather_hash.parsed_response['location']['state']
  end
```

Finally, be sure you're referencing `@weather_lookup` somewhere in your view, else the data won't show. A simple, unformatted example:

```
<%= @weather_lookup %>
```

Assuming the logic works in your model, the JSON should render after you submit a ZIP code via the form. I don't have an API key else I would have tested this myself.

Comment: thanks a million! this does exactly what I want it to do now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not hitting your home controller after you hit submit. Make sure you are routing correctly with

```
root to: 'pages#home'
```

and add this to your form

```
<%= form_tag(root_path, method: 'get') do %>
```